# Issue with Vendor and Employee Business Rules

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

According to the documentation, there is a Business Rule for Vendor and Employee that says

The name, first name, or last name field should not be blank.

Considering that NAME is required for create, the question is ¿Does this mean that ALL three properties have to have a value on Create?

We understood that, so we ran some tests. Creating a record with the three properties populated has no problem. The issue comes when we try so insert a null value for GivenName and FamilyName (first name and last name).

Quickbooks seems to take the NULL values as valid, and when inserting the record is not returning any error. The problem is that the record that was inserted never shows in the QBD UI, but is seems like it persists somewhere, because if we try to insert it again we get a "duplicate name" error.

Not sure if this is an issue or an expected behaviour... Any hints??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

QuickBooks for windows has some legacy behavior to be aware of. The First, Last and Name combines for a unique identifier accross Customers, Vendors and Employees. So you should fill in ALL the information you have. Any attempts to insert a record with the same F or L name, will fail if there is a Customer, Vendor or Employee with the same F & L.

Second, you mentioned that the record doesn't show in QuickBooks for Windows?
Did it sync successfully? Did you check the error state of the record you inserted?
Did you look at the sync logs to see if it failed to sync?

Lastly, you need to check all three objects for a user with the same F & L name if you are getting a duplicate error. Normally you would check to see if the customer/vendor/employee exists firsts so you can update the existing or determine if it is in fact a new record.

hope that helps
Jarred

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your response...
We already learned that F and L name combinations should be unique accross Customer, Vendor and Employee entities.. 

About the record not being displayed in QBD and your questions. 
1. The Sync ends with no error
2. How do I check the error state? I am calling VendorQuery, and the Vendor I inserted without either F or L name shows there, but I can't see any property showing an error state. I see ObjectState, which shows "ReadOnly" (same as the rest)

Comment: 3. I checked the Sync Logs but I can't find anywhere if it tells me that a record failed to sync. Could you specify what type of error or message should I look for?
Here is a link to the file if you want to check: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5654637/apps/D09A008C21111E35E040900A441A3C12_IntuitSyncManagerLogger.log

We mentioned that the duplicate error is shown when we try to insert AGAIN a record that was inserted before with either F or L name nulled, just to prove that the record has been inserted the first time, somewhere, but we can't see it in the UI... Hope I am being clear.

thanks!